# Define method declaration which argument is a implementation type

Tags: scala

I have a class `Calculator` which extends a function. The function argument type is a trait called `InputData` and the function output type another trait `OutputData`.

I need to override the `apply` method. The problem is, I can't have as  argument a case class which extends `InputData`.

```scala
class Calculator extends (InputData => OutputData) {
  override def apply(data: Numbers): MathResult = { ... }
}

case class Numbers(x1: Int, x2: Int) extends InputData

case class MathResult(y: Int) extends OutputData
```

When I try to do like this, I get `Method 'apply' overrides nothing`.

Comment: ham, if you said that `Calculator` extends a **function** from `InputData` to `OutputData`. Then you can not simply ignore that, and use a different type in `apply`. You are breaking both the interface and the Liskov Substitution Principle as a consequence to the first one. Why did you wanted to do this?

Comment: But `Numbers` extends `InputData`, isn't it a valid argument? I think my assumption isn't right ...

Comment: Yes it is a valid argument, but it is insufficient. Because you said you were capable of handling all `InputDatas` in the world. But then, you lied, and said you can only support `Numbers`, can you see where this is going? - The **Liskov Substitution Principle** states that if `A` is a subtype of `B` you can replace all occurrences of `B` with `A`. If I would change every occurrence of `InputData => OutputData` with `Calculator` I would get a lot of runtime errors. You can either, said it extends `Numbers => MathResult` instead.

Comment: let's start with something more philosophical: we don't just abstract things for fun, we abstract them when there's need.
you don't provide the traits of InputData and OutputData, what do they include? what is the purpose of this very abstract input -> output mapping?
you could just as easily say that Calculator maps Any to Any - but then the types don't serve you, you serve them. 
every function in the world maps some input to some output, how is this beneficial information? where is the added benefit of this abstraction?

Comment: Got it! Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't be done.

1. Method argument says that it can receive every `InputData` subtype, if you specify a concrete type for the argument, you are actually restricting the input type, breaking the method declaration, so the error `Method 'apply' overrides nothing`. (Thanks @Luis)
2. Actually, this abstraction isn't necessary for the use case. You can declare a method called `apply` and still able to invoke with open and close parenthesis. (Thanks @natan)